# On every product page, I get a product-specific png;base64 error like this

Tags: image, http-status-code-404, png, custom-error-pages

On every product page, I get a product-specific png;base64 error like this, but I couldn't solve my problem. I'm waiting for your help.

it crashes to 404 error

https://example.com/vare/glat-gas-stegeplade-forkromet-skab-gennemgang-2/image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAALCAYAAABLcGxfAAAAI0lEQVQokWNkYGD4z4AE/t5SReYyfIqURuEzMZAIRjUMUQ0A/GYEd0rV8WkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

[url error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaiDZ.png)